# Making it easier understand changes from a pull-request or diff

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

We've got a relatively large team working on one codebase.  We have a fairly mature process in place to ensure changes are reviewed before they get merged to our main line.

The problem that I have is that sometimes change sets are very "large". They touch a large number of files, adding/removing methods, creating brand new classes, and more.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to "browse" the changes, instead of a straight text diff.  Ideally, I'd like to see a navigable summary of added/removed/renamed functions/methods.  Of course, I'd also like to see modified functions, and config files, etc...

We're using git and Stash.  We also tend to use JetBrains products, if that makes a difference. (IntelliJ IDEA, PhpStorm)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's nothing like this for Stash; it can syntax highlight some files, but that's about it. You would need to write a plugin to display diffs in a different way.

You might have better luck with [JetBrains Upsource](https://www.jetbrains.com/upsource/), as it includes plugins for their IDEs to do code review "inside the IDE". Of course, since the IDE knows all about the methods, members, classes, and whatever else you've got going on, it should be easier to figure out what a commit is actually changing. Of course, you can achieve the same thing with a Stash pull-request by simply checking out the branch to be merged and inspecting the changes in your IDE.